# Getting online calclulation in PHP

Tags: php

Alright so I am using file_get_contents to get the output from a website, now I am basically trying to get the result from this website

Example

> http://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=44.784129%2C+20.489507&to=44.782793%2C+20.506533&units=k

How do I do it? I mean this is my current code but as you can see it display basically the entire website

```
function getDistance($x, $y, $xA, $yA) {
        $distance_ = file_get_contents("http://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=".$x."+".$y."&to=".$xA."+".$yA."&units=k");
        echo $distance_;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want from that page? The value under the `distance` heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to get the distance, here's a rough example of how:

```
$distance = file_get_contents('url');

//match all td elements since the data is tabular
preg_match_all('/<td.*(.*?)<\/td>/si', $distance, $matches); 
//remove html tags
$string = strip_tags($matches[0][0]);

$distance = substr($string, -26); //ouput is string(26) "1.36 kilometers E (96°)--"
```